# C++ Dependent Type in CRTP (regression MSVC2017 v15.7.2?)

Tags: c++, using, crtp, dependent-type

This works in MSVC2017 v15.6, but fails in MSVC2017 v15.7.2:

```
struct Foo { using T = int; };

template<class DERIVED, class WRAP>
struct A { using T = typename WRAP::T; };

template<class DERIVED>
struct B : public A<DERIVED, Foo> {
  B(T t);  //error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'T'
};
```

***Desired*:  The `using` declarations in the `BASE` are exposed for use in the `DERIVED`.**

The fix for MSVC2017 v15.7.2 seems to be:

```
template<class DERIVED>
struct B : public A<DERIVED, Foo> {
  using BASE = A<DERIVED, Foo>;
  using T = typename BASE::T;  // ??expose again??
  B(T t);   // OK (MSVC 2018 v15.7.2)
};
```

***Is this a regression*** in MSVC2017 v15.7.2, or is this expected C++ behavior?

Note that this question is different from:

*- [Type not found when derived from template base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236870/type-not-found-when-derived-from-template-base-class)

...because why is the `public using` in the `BASE` no longer visibile in the `DERIVED` ?

Comment: This is not the basic question about how dependent types work nor the known issues with MSVC. Please refrain from closing the question with answers to the basic question.

Comment: For your last question: `T` is dependent on its template parameters. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527849/how-do-you-understand-dependent-names-in-c

Comment: Agree (`T` is dependent type), but that is resolved in `BASE` through re-exporting from the `Foo` concrete type.  It seems nonsensical that `BASE::T` and `DERIVED::T` could resolve to different types when parameterized with concrete type `Foo`.  So, why must `DERIVED::T` be explicitly resolved again?